# How to Align images horizontally in HTML/CSS(float and display inline-block don't work)

Tags: html, css

I had a gallery of images lines up horizontally but then I made it so that the images have a text overlay when you hover and now nothing that I used to use to get items to line up horizontally works. I'm tried using float left on all the selectors (and likewise with display inline-block) but nothing

```
    <div class = "gallery">
      <div>
        <div class = "container">
            <img src="Images/ConorWhisky.jpg" class = "img"><div class = "overlay">
            <div class = "text">Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class = "container">
            <img src = "Images/Cricket.jpg" class = "img">
            <div class = "overlay">
            <div class = "text">Hello</div>
            </div>    
         </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
<style>

    .container{
        position:relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .gallery{
        width: 25%;
        padding: 0vw;
        margin: 3%;
        border-radius: 5vw;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 5%
    }

    .img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 120%;
    }

    .overlay{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 95%;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: .5s ease;
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }


    .container:hover .overlay{
        opacity: 1;

    }

    .text{
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 2vw;
        font-family: 'poppins',sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }



</style>
```

Comment: why do you have a `<div>` that is wrapping around the `container` ? why are you using `display:inline-block` on gallery ? don't you want the containers to stay side-by-side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex`; you can learn about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0vw;
  margin: 3%;
  border-radius: 5vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 5%
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="Images/ConorWhisky.jpg" class="img">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="Images/Cricket.jpg" class="img">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: worked a treat. Thank you mysterious stranger (rep's not enough to show my upvote)

Answer (score 0):

Updated your css with following snippet...

```css
.container,
.gallery > div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.gallery {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 3%;
    border-radius: 5vw;
    float: left;
}

.img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 95%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div>
        <div class="container"> <img src="Images/ConorWhisky.jpg" class="img">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Hello</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="container"> <img src="Images/Cricket.jpg" class="img">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Hello</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your HTML and CSS and used `flexbox` properties to achieve your layout. This avoids using `float` and `inline-block`

```css
.gallery {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 3%;
  border-radius: 5vw;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300" class="img">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300" class="img">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```